# MuleStudio Unexpected element error with Salesforce Connector

Tags: salesforce, mule-studio

Salesforce changes to TLS v1.1 and higher protocols has forced us to initiate a change on our Mule Installation setup, hosted on Mule Standalone version 3.4 with JDK 6. Post the JDK 7 update and enabling the HTTPS Protocol parameters I am seeing a issue performing a connection to Salesforce

```
Unexpected element.Test connection failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDisallowHtmlAttachments' but found 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDefaultCurrencyLocale' org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDisallowHtmlAttachments' but found 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDefaultCurrencyLocale' at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.reconnect(SalesforceConnector.java:381) at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.connect(SalesforceConnector.java:342)
```

Comment: I am imagining the issue is purely related to my setup, considering no responses from the forum :)

Comment: hi where can we get the latest Mule Community Connectors for Salesforce.

Comment: Including full trace for reference for test.salesforce.com Test connection failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDisallowHtmlAttachments' but found 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDefaultCurrencyLocale'
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDisallowHtmlAttachments' but found 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:orgDefaultCurrencyLocale'
 at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.reconnect(SalesforceConnector.java:386)
 at